# DBAdvGrid Show Decimal numbers

Tags: mysql, delphi, formatting, decimal

I have mysql table and DBAdvGrid,

decimal numbers of mysql column are shown like 950, 450, 555.45
I would like to be always shown 2 digits after point. like 950.00

I tried event of dataset 'AfterOpen'

TFloatField(MyDs.FieldByName('Price')).DisplayFormat := '0.00';

but did not helps

any help would appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

you can try (use the Dataset direct)
works with mysql and Zeos

```
(MyDs.FieldByName('Price') as TFloatField).DisplayFormat := '#####0.00';
```

to get what you want.

More information look here.

[Delphi's Database Architecture](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+13+Delphi+s+Database+Architecture/The+Fields+of+a+Dataset/)

UPDATE

About the test

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ZQuery1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.ZQuery1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
if CheckBox1.Checked then
(ZQuery1.FieldByName('gebuehr') as
    TFloatField).DisplayFormat := '#####0.00';
end;
```

Field `gebuehr`  Transl.(gebuehr == fee)

Without AfterOpen

[image]

With AfterOpen

[image]

Comment: I am trying to put code above in AfterOpen event of TZQuery, but no help.

I am using Zeos TZQuery and DBAdvGrid.

(MyDs.FieldByName('Price') as TFloatField).DisplayFormat := '#####0.00';

unfortunately did not help.

maybe am I putting it in wrong event?

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I had doubt that my DBAdvGrid was not showing decimals nevertheless that text was formatted as decimal, I have tested your code and did not worked for DBAdvGrid, but worked fine on DBGrid (I took it for testing).
Please take a look at this picture:

http://pix.ge/x/b/q/gkx7p/

sorry I am newbe and I can only make comments not posts.



if you have experience on DBAdvGrid, please let me know how to let it show decimals. anyway thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @user3259999 : strange behavior of `DBAdvGrid` :-(

Comment: yes, but never mind, I am gonna take new grid, that will solve my problem.

thanks again for helpful comments. :)

Comment: I got it now, problem was with pagemode property of DBAdvGrid
setting true - allowing decimal, setting false - not.
weird...

Comment: @user3259999 : That's what i want to tell just now . You are faster. TDBAdvGrid with `PageMode` property set true
This is the default mode for TDBAdvGrid. With PageMode = true, the behaviour of TDBAdvGrid most
closely resembles the behaviour of the Borland TDBGrid.

Comment: yes, I got another problem here:
I used PageMode = false for internal sorting.
by clicking column header it was sorting ASC and DESC.
now with PageMode = true, decimals are showing, but sorting does not work anymore :(

Comment: @user3259999 : make your sort by the `SQL` with `ORDER BY` after clicking the column header.

Comment: only close the dataset . set a new `query` and reopen.

Comment: excuse me for being so pushy. DBAdvGrid does not offer event for clicking header? I could not find it in list.

Comment: is there no TDBgrid like `DBGrid1TitleClick(Column: TColumn);` ?

Comment: no, not TitleClick but there is OnCanSort(Sender: TObject; ACol: Integer; var DoSort: Boolean); event that is similar. occurs while clicking header.